# Nested PCRE Regex Issue

Tags: php, regex, nested

I have a custom template engine.

It catch this :

```
@function(argument1 argument2 ...)
@get(param:name)
@get(param:@get(sub:name))
```

And this :

```
@function(argument1 argument2 ...)

    Some stuff @with(nested:tag)

    @foreach(arguments as value)
        More stuff : @get(value)
    @/foreach

    @function(other:args)
        Same function name (nested)
    @/function

@/function
```

With this pattern (PCRE / PHP) :

```
#

@ ([\w]+) \(

( (?: [^@\)] | (?R) )+ )

\)

(?:
    ( (?> (?-2) ) )

    @/\\1
)?

#xms
```

This regex catch almost all results. But when i have more nested (or not) tags, then it catch nothing. **For example**, when i do 2 nested `@foreach(var:name) ... @/foreach` then the regex will fail depending of the tag content `spaces`.

Comment: Are you trying to simply check if the input follows a certain format? Or are you trying to extract something out of it?

Comment: Regular expressions cannot generally handle nested patterns. Some RE engines have recursion, but I don't think PHP does.

Comment: @Barmar: PCRE does support [recursion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

Comment: @AmalMurali I extract `function`, `arguments`, and the tag content if any.

Comment: @Barmar PHP support recursion with `?(R)` and other things like atomic groups.

Comment: @user2715533: So what would be the expected output in this case?

Comment: Thanks, I just checked out the www.regular-expressions.info page and it confirms that

Comment: @AmalMurali Here, with a simple `@foreach(var:name) content @/foreach` the output of `preg_match_all` with `PREG_SET_ORDER` will be `array(0 => "@forea..", 1 => "foreach", 2 => "var:name", 3 => "content")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using named subpatterns is sometimes more clear. I suggest you to use this:

```
~
@(?<com>\w+)                 # command name
\s*                          # possible white characters before args
(?: \( (?<args>[^)]*) \) )?+ # eventual parameters
(?:
    (?<content>(?:[^@]+|(?R))*+) # content (maybe empty)
    @/\g{com}                    # close the command
)?+                          # optional
~
```

If you need to allow commands inside arguments, you can replace `(?<args>[^)]*)` with `(?<args>(?:[^@)]+|(?=@)(?R))*+)`

But a better way when you are trying to describe a language is to use the `(?(DEFINE)...)`  syntax to describe elements first, before the main pattern, example:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<command_name> \w+ )
    (?<inline_command> @ \g<command_name> \s* \g<params>? )
    (?<multil_command> @ (\g<command_name>) \s* \g<params>? \g<content> @/ \g{-1} )
    (?<command> \g<multil_command> | \g<inline_command> )

    (?<other> [^@()]+ ) 
    (?<param> \g<other> | \g<command> )
    (?<params> \( \s* \g<param> (?: \s+ \g<param> )* \s* \) )

    (?<content> (?: \g<other> | \g<command> )* )
)
# main pattern
\g<command>
~x
EOD;
```

With this kind of syntax, if you want to extract elements at the ground level, you only need to change the main pattern to: `@(?<com> \g<command_name> ) \s* (?<args>\g<params> )? (?: (?<con> \g<content> ) @/ \g{com} )?` (NB: To obtain other levels, put it inside a lookahead)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried each of your edits. The last is working. Except with this kind of tag `@load(@get(layout:control))`. Here, the tag content, does not match last `args` parenthesis. (Every time i tried, i could not match nested content tag, and nested args tags at the same time)

Comment: @user2715533: if commands are allowed inside the arguments parts, you can replace the args description with: `(?<args>(?>[^@)]++|(?=@)(?R))*)` instead of `(?<args>[^)]*)`

Comment: @user2715533: The best when you try to describe a language is to use named patterns and the `(?(DEFINE)...)` syntax. I will post an example.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. I will follow your advice.

Comment: I have a question with defined patterns. How do you retrieve patterns values ? (With your example, i would like to know how to retrieve command, args and content. Instead of all command value).

Comment: @user2715533: You can't! The only way is to capture inside the main pattern.